# How to improve model accuracy by redistributing training data over test, validation, and training data subsets after training

Tags: accuracy

How do I improve model accuracy by redistributing training data over test, validation, and training data subsets after training, and then training a new model with the updated data subsets.

The model has 60 inputs and 3 outputs. The total number of (balanced) exemplars is around 10k.

The data subset splits and the accuracies of the trained model on the subsets were as follows:

test subset 30% (accuracy 78%)
validation subset 21% (accuracy 80%)
training subset 49% (accuracy 99.8%)

Should I experiment with swapping half of the miss-classified exemplars from the validation and test subsets with an equal number of correctly classified exemplars in the training subset?